# Approximation of internal switching schematic in a LED driver chip

Tags: switching, pullup, led-driver, pulldown

[HT1632C datasheet](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/439827/HOLTEK/HT1632C.html)

I'm trying to figure out what would be an approximated schematic for the LED driver's COMMON pins when in the N-MOS open drain output mode.

The name suggests that there are N-channel MOSFET transistors involved. This is also confirmed by the fact that in the N-MOS mode the ON mode for a COMMON is with the pin pulled to ground.

[image: N-MOS open drain mode HT1632C datasheet excerpt]

*On the diagram above the OFF state is VCC (3.3V in my case) and the the ON state is ground.*

What is not clear to me is what happens in the OFF state for the COM pins on the diagram above. From probing with an oscilloscope I can tell that the COM pins in the OFF state do not have bult-in pull-ups and are in some way connected to ground because with no pull-ups attached externally the volate on the COM pins is floating near ground chaning only very insignificantly between the ON and OFF states.

When I add a 100K pullup to 5.1V (this is intentionally higher than the 3.3V VCC of the chip itself in my case) I get 3.8V for the OFF state. My first guess was that it has a 300K pull-down to ground inside the chip when in the OFF state but when I connect a 1K pull-up I get 4.1V for the OFF state which means this is not just a simple pull-down inside the chip.

What could be an approximate schematic for this swtiching inside the chip that would explain these volatage with these external pull-up resistors?

Comment: It is likely to be built-in ESD protection diodes at the pins. The diodes would clamp the voltage to one diode drop above Vcc, which matches what you described.

Comment: Why would the pins then sit at ground all the time (both ON and OFF) with no external pull-up connected?

Comment: @rioraxe just tested your suggestion in LTSpice and the behavior appears to be what I'm observing. Thanks! A screenshot of the LTSPICE model: http://i.imgur.com/oMqebSs.png